# How do I target a nested HTML element with PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently working through some trouble with Advanced Custom Fields and wpkses filters. So far, I've been able to pass iframe, script, style, and noscript tags through. This google tag manager is  and the iframe is being caught in wpkses and put in quotes. This is what I have so far:

```
function allow_iframe_script_tags( $allowedposttags ) {
    $allowedposttags['script'] = array(
        'type' => true,
        'src' => true,
    );

    $allowedposttags['noscript'] = array();

    // Also allow iframe directly
    $allowedposttags['iframe'] = array(
        'src' => true,
        'height' => true,
        'width' => true,
    );

    $allowedposttags['style'] = array();

    return $allowedposttags;
}

add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', 'allow_iframe_script_tags', 10, 1 );
```

I thought that maybe the order in which they were written would end up passing the iframe just fine, and it doesn't. I've tried a few variations:

```
$allowedposttags['noscript']['iframe'] = true;
```

and

```
$allowedposttags['noscript'] = array(
        'iframe' => array(
            'src' => true,
            'height' => true,
            'width' => true,
        ),
    );
```

Super thankful for any help.

```
$allowedposttags['noscript']['iframe'] = true;
```

and

```
$allowedposttags['noscript'] = array(
        'iframe' => array(
            'src' => true,
            'height' => true,
            'width' => true,
        ),
    );
```

Both ended up still passing the nested iframe in quotes.

Comment: I don’t have an answer for your specific problem at the moment, but I just wanted to comment that the original point of KSES was to block scripts, and I think the modern concern would also be CSS and iframes. So making a global change to bypass this for one field doesn’t seem like a good idea. Can you instead modify the specific field, and/or maybe use a text area instead?

Comment: totally understand the concerns, but this would end up alienating Google Tag Manager, a tool that is used by a huge chunk of the web dev community. It's not just one field, it's multiple instances where tracking from other apps requires additional scripts.

Comment: Yep, I use GTM on every single site. (Personally I just use Google Site Kit to install it. It is overkill, but it is auditable by my clients.) My concern is that your are globally filtering `wp_kses_allowed_html` to allow scripts everywhere on a site. I also understand that you want to potentially enable multiple scripts in multiple locations, but does it need to be done in a WYSIWYG context? Can you not just expose "something" that is dedicated to this, and have that not run through wp_kses?

Comment: Great suggestion with GSK and will probably advise that route re: GTM. I even tried embedding the code directly into the header.php theme files after the body opened and kses still stripped it. Does that sound right? Would I need to write a specific php page with all of these tracking tags that starts with a "no touchy wp_kses"?

Comment: Anything you added to files such as header.php or footer.php should be 100% unaffected by KSES. The only way for KSES to affect these would be some sort of internal request that scrapes those files. I guess if you used the WordPress theme editor to edit those files, maybe it could get in the way, too. But if you just used FTP/SSH they shouldn't be affected.